# Redirect to cck url on registration?

Tags: entities

I have a node that has a cck field that has a link, when the person clicks on it, I need them to sign up then redirect to that link.

Is that possible?

logintoboggan, rules and login destination cant achieve this, they only send to one defined page.

Comment: Correct me if I"m wrong. Anonymous user -> sign up, then redirect to link.   Authenicated users ->  go direct to the link

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect to the login or registration page you can add a `destination` GET parameter to the url, which Drupal will redirect to after form submission.

Comment: For example, the link might be: http://example.com/user/register?destination=node/23. That ought to cause the user to land on node/23 after completing registration.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom module and implement hook_menu

```
function YOURMODULENAME_menu() {
  $items = array();
    $items['checkuser'] = array(
      'title' => '',
      'page callback' => 'check_user',
      'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
  return $items;
}

fucntion check_user() {
  $destination = $_GET['destination'];
  $is_login = user_is_logged_in();
  if($is_login) {
    drupal_goto($destination);
  }
  else {
    $options = array('query' => $destination);
    drupal_goto('user/register', $options);
  }
}
```

Use below snippet in your node template

```
l('Title', 'checkuser', array('query' => array('destination' => 'destination_url')));
```